# Java ArrayList starts with 1 not 0?

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm retrieving some data from `DB` with the `ff` code:

```
List<modelA> list= new ArrayList<modelA>();
list = modelA.getList(parameter);
```

This is what has been retrieved:

```
list[1] = "var1"

list[2] = "var2"

list[3] = "var3"
```

`list.size() = 3` and `list[0]` does not exist.

I transferred the list to a LinkedHashSet to set the indexes right, but it doesn't work. The list is still the same.

```
Set<modelA> hs = new LinkedHashSet<>();
hs.addAll(list);
list.clear();
list.addAll(hs);
```

Is there a way to fix the indexes so that it will start with 0 and not 1?

This is the error when I run `list.get(0)`

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at applicationmodels.f08.pv.F08PV008Model.search(F08PV008Model.java:221)
    at controllers.f08.pv.F08PV008.control(F08PV008.java:148)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$99$$anonfun$apply$99.apply(routes_routing.scala:1510)
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$99$$anonfun$apply$99.apply(routes_routing.scala:1510)
    at play.core.Router$HandlerInvoker$$anon$7$$anon$2.invocation(Router.scala:183)
    at play.core.Router$Routes$$anon$1.invocation(Router.scala:377)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$1.call(JavaAction.scala:56)
    at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction$1.apply(TransactionalAction.java:20)
    at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction$1.apply(TransactionalAction.java:18)
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.withTransactionAsync(JPA.java:177)
    at play.db.jpa.TransactionalAction.call(TransactionalAction.java:15)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:91)
    at play.core.j.JavaAction$$anon$3.apply(JavaAction.scala:90)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
    at play.core.j.FPromiseHelper$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(FPromiseHelper.scala:82)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:251)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(Future.scala:249)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at play.core.j.HttpExecutionContext$$anon$2.run(HttpExecutionContext.scala:37)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:42)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Comment: Are you sure that in the size size of `liste.size()` is 3 and not 4?

Comment: what is modelA.getList? the returned List implementation might use non-zero based indexes

Comment: What is the value of `list[0]` anyway? `null`?

Comment: post bit more code that will help to resolve issue.

Comment: the size is 3 and there is no index 0. modelA.getList is a JPA model

Comment: 1) what are you using to interact with db, 2) what is a type of `list` 3) what you will get if you call list.get(0)  will it return null or throw exception?

Comment: @user902383 list.get(0) will give null pointer exception, I also use play.db.JPA

Comment: @Alice it sounds interesting, could you post stacktrace from that exception? is is really interesting. also what is a type of `list` object? is it belongs to java api? is it some kind of proxy?

Comment: @user902383 I'm sorry what do you mean by "what is a type of list object?". Also, I think the  problem may be due to some data anomaly in the DB which I do not have control over.

Comment: @Alice list implements `List` interface, i was wonder about implementations, is it from java api, or is it custom made.  i wonder what would happen if you do `List<modelA> list= new ArrayList<>(modelA.getList(parameter));` this should copy content to new instance of`ArrayList` and fix indexing. if this list type is custom made, it explains why it didn't work when you add data from set

Answer (score 0):

```
list = modelA.getList(parameter);
```

Your method getList from modelA class returns a built list. The way it builts the list can be anything. It can starts even in position 99.

So, you need to check/fix how the objects are being placed in the list in your modelA class.

Comment: is there no way to fix the list using java, because I'm not allowed to touch the model

Comment: So, your only possibility is to remove the first element before use your list. Although, it does not seems to be a real problem. Just mind to not use the first element of the list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `getList` method returns a `List` implementation which violates the API (assuming List is java.util.List). The api for [List.get()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) specifies that all List implementations should throw IndexOutOfBoundsException if `index == list.size()`.
You could create a list of some specific type you choose (e.g. an ArrayList) and put the contents of the broken List in the list you created:

```
List<modelA> list= new ArrayList<modelA>(modelA.getList(parameter));
```

Then you should get a list of size 3 where zero-based indexing is used.

---

Optionally, you could check what the type of the broken List implementation is:

```
System.out.println(modelA.getList(parameter).getClass().getName());
```

And try to fix the implementation of the broken List class. But this might be risky if there is code elsewhere which relies on the 1-based indexing of this List implementation.